# "This Site Can't Be Reached" Chrome Error

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet, browser

I have been trying to access Firefox and Chrome on my Ubuntu system but it always end up with this screen.

> Your connection to this site is not secure
>
> This site can't be reached

My VPN is switched off and I have not installed any antivirus also.

Can you please help me out?

Comment: Have you tried after after all temporary data such as cookies and cache?

Comment: Yeah, Even I have done that.

Comment: Are you encountering this on a particular site or all sites?

Comment: Can you screenshot the full error messages you're seeing and add links to those screenshots in your post?  There's likely more information than is being provided here hidden in the messages that will help explain what you're actually running into in terms of problems.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?  Can you post the Certificate Authorities on the https cert?

Comment: If your connection to the site is encrypted (https:// instead of http://, nowadays most sites use encrypted connections), the problem might be there somewhere. Maybe the site's certificate ran out, maybe the certificate authority that issued the certificate isn't trusted anymore, maybe there are no protocols and/or ciphers that both the site and your browser can handle.

Comment: Do pings work? `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com`